# TCP SYN Flooding Detection Method in the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, kernel

When the Linux kernel detects SYN Flooding it logs a message like:

`possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies`

Does anyone know the exact method that the kernel uses to detect this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm reading the sysctl/tcp stuff correctly, it's tripped when the number of un-ACKed syn requests exceeds the value of net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog.  Specifically:

> The tcp_max_syn_backlog variable tells
>   your box how many SYN requests to keep
>   in memory that we have yet to get the
>   third packet in a 3-way handshake
>   from. The tcp_max_syn_backlog variable
>   is overridden by the tcp_syncookies
>   variable, which needs to be turned on
>   for this variable to have any effect.
>   If the server suffers from overloads
>   at peak times, you may want to
>   increase this value a little bit.

The reason I think it's that simple is the text from tcp_syncookies:

> The tcp_syncookies variable is used to
>   send out so called syncookies to hosts
>   when the kernels syn backlog queue for
>   a specific socket is overflowed. This
>   means that if our host is flooded with
>   several SYN packets from different
>   hosts, the syn backlog queue may
>   overflow, and hence this function
>   starts sending out cookies to see if
>   the SYN packets are really legit.

To me that makes it sound like it really is as simple as the syn queue having > tcp_max_syn_backlog outstanding connections.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies) on `SYN` cookies might help.  You can, of course, [examine the source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c?v=2.6.33).